# Can Unburied bodies cause plagues?

Tags: books, history-of

I've read several books that involve a massive civil war or conquest and often in these stories there is a link to unburied bodies being left in fields/villages causing a plague.

I've done some research on whether dead bodies can cause an outbreak of the plague, and so far the answer seems to be no.

[This World Health Organzation question and answer](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/emergencies/qa/emergencies_qa8/en/) makes it seem that the only concern of bodies laying around is water contamination.
[This Center for Disease Control 'plague sheet'](https://www.cdc.gov/plague/resources/235098_Plaguefactsheet_508.pdf) doesn't mention it either.

So, is unburied bodies causing a plague just a trope? Is there any historical reference of a plague **starting** from a pile of dead bodies (I understand that contact with a corpse that died from the plague can transfer it).

Some examples from this in books:

- In the *Malazan Book of the Fallen* book *The Bonehunters*, Ganoes Paran

  > mentions that a plague is ravaging through Seven Cities, likely a result of all the slaughter and unburied bodies.
- Another series that comes to mind is the *Ashes* series by William Johnstone

  > where following the nuclear war, a large group of rats carrying fleas with a plague from all of the dead bodies left behind is a menace to the group for a couple of books.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plague Apparently 'plague' has two meanings relevant here.  'The plague' is the disease resulting from Yersina Pestis infection, while 'a plague' just means a generic lethal epidemic.

Comment: @b.Lorenz Well, the more you know. I guess I was being too literal when reading plague and thinking bubonic plague.

Comment: (1/2) Well, question's been closed before I could post it as an answer, but I suggest you take a look at [this CDC paper on the Black Death](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/8/9/01-0536_article). Long story short, the plague that killed up to one third (_one third!_) of Europe in the 14th century may have originated from corpses being catapulted into the besieged settlement of Caffa. Some sailors escaped, went on to their trades, and then the disease spread... That's the point of view from a local notary from that time.

Comment: (2/2) However, the CDC author reckons that while it was certainly biological warfare, its actual part in the spread may not have been the major one. It was one of several "burning points" that all were subjected to the plague at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have said in comment, it is quite possible that your references do not mean "the plague" ( the bubonic/septic bacterial infection), but just another -- possibly fictional -- disease.

**Naturally, it is not possible to create Pestis bacteria from corpses if they are not already there.** Yet unburied dead can contribute to the spread of a Plague outbreak: They mean food, thus balooning the numbers of the rat population. **After there are no more bodies, a large number of hungry and weakened rats mean ideal conditions for the plague to spread.**

The reason for the CDC to not mention it is that masses of unburied dead lying around for weeks is a non-issue in present day US.